# Google Map stretches on view resize

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have the following problem - I have to display a map in a small view on the screen and when the user clicks on it to resize it.
The problem is that when I change the view that contains the map to be on full screen the map stretches for a few milliseconds.
So do you know a good event on which I can attach so to know when the map is visualised correctly?

Thanks and Kind Regards

Comment: It depends on the Internet Speed if it is slow it will take time to load it's not a problem of container

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually it has to be loaded already. The problem is that every time when you change the state from a small window to a full screen it first stretches the map for a few milliseconds and then the map is displayed correctly. I tried to hide the map for 200ms and then to show it and it works but sometime if the device is overloaded it might again be displayed incorrectly for a few milliseconds so this is why I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue. I think that using animations is the way to go, I will try it out.

Comment: any solution ?
I am also facing such problem,

Comment: same issue here...